# Gridview condition for each row by checking for each row from Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am working on an ASP.NET project. It has all the code in server side tags Grid view is implemented for fetching records, so now we have a requirement as listed below:

> for each record or each single table row we have to make an http request and check a condition of the record if it satisfies then the record should display and not otherwise. SO I thought to make a stored procedure and do everything in stored procedure and return only 10 filtered records at a time or on paging.

Can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: So, you have a problem and possible solution. What you is your question again? BTW I still recommend to try implementing the solution first and then ask the question after

Comment: By everything you mean filtering the records? How can you filter if filtering implies making an httprequest? Do you "own" the code for the endpoint you need to call?